# How to select the node with the highest number of incoming relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database with 3 types of nodes:
**articles** (in blue)
**entities** (in pink)
and **solution** (in green).
They are linked with **APPEARS_IN** or **PART_OF** relationships.
[image: Structure of the dataset]

I'm trying to select the solution node which has **the hishest number of incoming relationships** ("Link with Unity Pro en Français"), I tryed with this query with a threshold (>2) but it is not exactly what I want to do, because here I know that the highest number of incoming relationship is 3, but it can be different for other examples:

```
MATCH (q:Question {title:"Comment avoir l'aide en ligne en français sur Unity Pro?"})<-[:APPEARS_IN]-(e:Entity)
MATCH (e:Entity)-[r:PART_OF]->(s:Solution)
WITH collect(e) AS entities, s, count(r) AS num WHERE num > 2
RETURN s
```

**How can I find the 'solution' node or nodes (in green) with the highest number of incoming relationships?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the query like this :

```
MATCH (e:Entity)-[r:PART_OF]->(s:Solution)
WITH e, s, size((s)<--()) AS incomingCount
ORDER BY incomingCountDesc
RETURN s
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: There is no need for the `MATCH` to get the `Entity` node or `PART_OF` relationship.

Answer (score 1):

To efficiently get the `Solution` node with the largest number of incoming relationships:

```
MATCH (s:Solution)
RETURN s, SIZE((s)<--()) AS cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The `SIZE((s)<--())` syntax causes the Cypher planner to generate a very efficient [GetDegree](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-counting-number-of-relationships-on-a-node/) operation, which does not require any DB hits.