# How can I select nodes that have zero relationships except pointing to themselves?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'd like to get the nodes which only point to themselves and have no relationships with other nodes (only to themselves):

```
MATCH (z:zone) WHERE NOT (z)-[:CONNECTS]->(:zone) RETURN z
```

The result should include Newark Airport and Baisley Park as we can see those two nodes still have a relationship but isolated to other nodes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATE]

Neo4j 5.0 introduced the new [COUNT subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#count-subqueries) expression, which makes it easier to invoke the efficient [getDegree operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64558710/974731). However, one end of the pattern used in the subquery will still need to be unspecific to take advantage of `getDegree`.

For example, the ORIGINAL query below can be rewritten in 5.0 as:

```
MATCH (z:zone)-[:CONNECTS]->(z)
WHERE COUNT { (z)-[:CONNECTS]->() } = 1
RETURN z
```

[ORIGINAL]

The following query is very efficient, as it takes advantage of the [getDegree operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64558710/974731), which does not require any db hits. You can [profile](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/query-profile/) the query to verify this.

```
MATCH (z:zone)-[:CONNECTS]->(z)
WHERE SIZE([(z)-[:CONNECTS]->()|1]) = 1
RETURN z
```

NOTE 1: In order to use `getDegree`, the [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) within the `SIZE()` function must be unspecific about one of the end nodes. This is why `()` is used on one end above.

NOTE 2: Neo4j 5 does not support the old syntax `SIZE((z)-[:CONNECTS]->())`, hence this answer uses a more-cumbersome pattern comprehension within the `SIZE()` function. The good news is that the Cypher query planner can still figure out that it can use `getDegree` with the new syntax.