# Check the nodes having two relationships of type IS_TRUE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to fetch all nodes of type `RULE` having two relationships of type `IS_TRUE` or `IS_FALSE` from the same node. I can extract nodes with a single relationship like this:

```
MATCH (r:RULE)-[:IS_TRUE]->(n)

RETURN r
```

But I want to check those nodes that are producing two or more edges having an `IS_TRUE` relationship. The above query only returns all nodes that are producing `IS_TRUE` relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the most efficient approach:

```
MATCH (r:RULE)
WHERE SIZE([(r)-[:IS_TRUE]->()|1]) = 2
RETURN r
```

This query's `SIZE` clause is constructed in such a way that it causes the Cypher query planner to use the `getDegree` operation, which does not need to hit the DB to get the number of relationships. Please read [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75525810/974731) for the details.