# How to make two Cypher optional matches not multiply results?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (:User)-[l:LIKED]->(:User {username: $username})
OPTIONAL MATCH (:User)-[d:DISLIKED]->(:User {username: $username})
RETURN count(l),count(d)
```

I have this Cypher query to return the count of 2 types of relationships. Currently there are 7 :LIKED edges and 5 :DISLIKED edges running into the given username, but when I run this I get both counts as 35. How can I change it to not be multiplied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the start node of every `LIKED` and `DISLIKED` relationship is always a `User`, then we can use a path pattern that leaves the start node unspecific. In this case, the most efficient way to get the counts is as follows (since it causes the Cypher planner to count relationships using the `getDegree` operation, which does not need to hit the DB):

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (u:User {username: $username})
RETURN
  SIZE([()-[:LIKED]->(u)|1]) AS count_l,
  SIZE([()-[:DISLIKED]->(u)|1]) AS count_d
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75523865/how-can-i-select-nodes-that-have-zero-relationships-except-pointing-to-themselve/75525810#75525810) to another question provides more details.

Comment: Thank you so much this works great! Can I know what the 1 does at `(u) | 1`?

Comment: A [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) is required to specify what should be added to the generated list for every pattern match. We could have specified `u`, but your use case is not trying to collect any nodes, so in such cases I try to make that clear by using a literal value like `1`. In fact, in this solution the list is not even generated at all, since the planner is smart enough to just use the `getDegree` operation.