# How to batch process millions of nodes and save the result into file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following schema in Neo4j:

```
(:Foo)-[:HAS]->(:Bar)
(:Foo)<-[:IN]-(:Baz)
```

There are tens of millions of `(:Foo)`, with potentially millions relationships between `(:Foo)` and `(:Baz)`.

I want to get the biggest `(:Foo)` (in terms of a number of relationships between `(:Foo)` and `(:Baz)`) which do not have any relationships with `(:Bar)`.

I was trying:

```
MATCH (f:Foo) WHERE NOT (f)-[:HAS]->(:Bar)
WITH f, count([(f)<-[:IN]-()]) as b_count WHERE b_count > 10 RETURN f, b_count
```

but that query never finishes.

I have also tried using `apoc.periodic.iterate`, but I don't know how to get the result.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (f:Foo) WHERE NOT (f)-[:HAS]->(:Bar) RETURN f", 
"WITH f, count([(f)<-[:IN]-()]) as b_count WHERE b_count > 10 RETURN f, b_count",
 {parallel:true, batchSize:1000})
```

Ideally, I would like to get the results sorted by `b_count` and return only the `N` biggest.

Sorting all the results to only get the biggest `N` might be too memory-demanding.
If the results could be saved to a file, I could use `sort` to order the results afterwards.

EDIT:

If possible, the query should be neo4j 3.5 compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75525810/974731), [COUNT subqueries](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#count-subqueries) allow you to take advantage of the very efficient `getDegree` operation (by avoiding any DB hits).

If all `HAS` relationships from a `Foo` node end in a `Bar` node, then you can simplify your first pattern to `(f)-[:HAS]->()` to take advantage of the `getDegree` operation twice in the same query:

```
MATCH (f:Foo)
WHERE COUNT { (f)-[:HAS]->() } = 0
WITH f, COUNT { (f)<-[:IN]-() } AS b_count
WHERE b_count > 10
RETURN f, b_count
```

This query should be very fast.

##### Prior to neo4j 5.0

If you are using a version of neo4j older than 5.0, you should be able to replace `COUNT { ... }` with `SIZE(...)` to use the `getDegree` operation. [Here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-counting-number-of-relationships-on-a-node/) is a knowledge base article about that.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using neo4j 3.5 and COUNT subquery is 5.0 feature.

Comment: I added info for older neo4j versions to the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One issue I see is that you are filtering on the `WHERE NOT` first. It's usually more efficient to find what you want, and then filter that down.

Try this instead:

```
match (f:Foo)<-[r:IN]->(:Bar)
where not (f)-[:HAS]->(:Baz)
with f, count(r) as count_b
order by count(r) desc
return f, count_b
limit N
```

Separately, `apoc.periodic.iterate` doesn't seem like the right solution here, since you don't actually want to do anything in batches. That command is better to set properties. You can get results out by invoking `yield` after the `call` but only on what it did; see the output section of https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/ for details.